# Mobile navigation dropdown not lining up

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive

I am making my website responsive and when I move to mobile version my navigation bar changes but now I am struggling with the dropdown within the navigation. I want the dropdown when I hover on it to appear on the left side of the vertical menu "Tours" dropdown.
Mobile Nav version hovering on the dropdown
[image]

```js
// JavaScript Document
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction(){
document.getElementsByClassName("Menu")
[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

```css
/*hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). 
Show the list item that contains the link to 
open and close the topnav (li.icon) */
.Menu li:not(:first-child)
{
display:none;
border-bottom:none;
}

.Menu li.icon
{
float:right;
display:inline-block;
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the Menu with JavaScript 
when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the Menu look good 
on small screens */
.Menu.responsive
{
position:relative;
}

.Menu.responsive li.icon
{
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:-4px;
border:none;
}

.Menu.responsive ul li.icon a
{
border-bottom:none;
}

.Menu.responsive li
{
float:none;
display:inline;

}

.Menu.responsive li a
{
display:block;
text-align:left;
background-color:#161616;
border-bottom:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown
{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

/*Dropdown arrow for link items*/
.caret
{
display: inline-block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin-left: 2px;
vertical-align: middle;
border-top: 4px dashed;
border-right: 4px solid transparent;
border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-menu
{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
min-width: 100px;
background-color: #161616;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* links inside the dropdown*/
.dropdown-menu a 
{
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
border-top:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
margin-top:0px;

}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-menu a:hover 
{
color: #755378;

}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu 
{
visibility:visible;
right: auto;
left: 0;
opacity:1;

}
```

```html
<div class="Menu"><!--Nav-menu-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="DropDown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tours <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Day Tours</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li> 
</ul>
</div><!--End Nav-menu-->
```

I added the Javascript for external purposes not actually needed this is just to make the menu responsive.

The Css is from my CssResponsive stylesheet for mobile version.

Comment: Try adding padding-left:0 to  .dropdown-menu  class.

Comment: unfortunately did not work, for some reason I can't get it to move to the left side of the nav bar